# Why won't my script remove files from folder larger than 1 mb?

Tags: windows, batch-file, authentication, command-line, scripting

I am writing a batch file to remove files larger than 1 MB  from a folder located on my desktop. But when running the script, it removes random items and not the ones over 1mb. Is my script wrote improperly?

```
for /R %%X in (C:\Users\TSwanson\Desktop\WorkSite) DO (
    IF %%~zX GTR 1024KB (ECHO DELETING "%%X"
    DEL /X "%%X"))
pause >Nul
```

Comment: User npocmaka is right in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37306640), but you also need to take into account, that numeric comparison is limited to 32-bit (signed) integers, so if a file is equal to or greater than 2 GB, the comparison may not work as expected...

Comment: I'm confused: first delete all files, then delete all files greater than... ?

Comment: Your right thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`IF "%%~zF" GEQ "10240"` the  quotes forces a alphabetical comparison.Try with:
`IF %%~zF GEQ 10240`